# Equivalent of one and half line spacing in terms pt

Tags: captions, line-spacing

I have the following decleration:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,noindent,nocenter,bold]{thesis}
```

The required format for captions of figures is that there should be a skip equal to 1.5 line. So, I do the following to get the required effect:

```
\usepackage[skip=18pt]{caption}
```

What I assume here is that `12pt x 1.5 = 18pt`, which I am not sure of its validity. Therefore:

1. How do we calculate equivalent of 1.5 line spacing in terms pt? If I want to make a line 1.5 of the a selected font manually, how should I calculate it?
2. Is there any way to assign value to skip dynamically? I mean instead of using `skip=18pt` (or any constant), can I use something like `skip=onehalfspacing` with or without using other packages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There are a *lot* of document classes named `thesis` available on the Internet. Please provide a link to the one you're using.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If you look at the documented code of `setspace`, one half spacing corresponds to a factor of 1.241 in 12pt. But as the `skip`in the `caption` package is the distance between caption and figure/table, they simply mean  `skip=1.5\baselineskip`. In points that would be  $\approx$ 22.5pt, but it's better to use the expression in `\baselineskip`.

Comment: @Mico I use standart thesis class that comes with MiKTeX

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for the solution and the explanations, could you also write it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Mehmed: Done. I've checked and corrected some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documented code of setspace, one half spacing corresponds to a factor of `1.241` in 12pt, `1.25` for 10 and 11pt. But as the `\skip` in the `caption` package denotes the distance between caption and figure/table, I think they simply mean `\skip=1.5\baselineskip`. In points that would be approximately 1.5×14=21.75pt, but it's better to use the expression in \baselineskip as it gives some elasticity.